python opencv connect to camera and cannot open your camera
I used Python and OpenCV to connect my program to camera IP.
I try to connect my camera to VLC tool, it can show camera normal. and try connect from python to camera as:
This is my sources:
import cv2

url = 'rtsp://myuser:mypassword@192.168.1.3:port/onvif1?rtsp_transport=udp'

# Open the video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # If the frame was not retrieved properly, break the loop
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to grab frame")
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Mobile Camera', frame)

    # Press 'q' to exit the video stream
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

when i run it happens an exception:
cannot open your camera..

How to fix the problem, thanks advanced

Try setting ffmpeg propertie rtsp-transport and set it to UDP If your Stream is only udp

yes, i will try this case

Try using TCP instead of UDP. Also ensure that u have ffmpeg installed.

"installed" ffmpeg has zero effect on the ffmpeg that OpenCV contains.
